# Ограничение поиска объектов по определённому региону

Tags: яндекс-карты

Интересует, есть ли возможность простым способом ограничить поиск по какому-то определённому региону, конкретно по Якутии.  Я пробовал через `SearchControl` и `boundedBy`, предварительно получив границы области через

```
ymaps.regions.load('RU', {
    lang: 'en',
    quality: 1
})
```

и получив по коду нужный регион, использовав метод `getBounds`, но что-то не работает.

Даже, если поставить координаты в `SearchControl`

```
var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    boundedBy:[[71.95152553383006,124.77785662500001], [60.89422088315866,153.51809099999997]],
    noPlacemark: true,
    strictBounds: true
});
myMap.controls.add(searchControl);
```

то всё равно можно через автокомплит найти Москву, которой, по идее быть не должно.

Автоподбор почему-то зависит от видимой области на карте. Например если я смотрю на Москву, то в приоритете будут Московские адреса.

В провайдере стоит `# map`

```
myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
  center: [62.15187236180695,129.7922575],
  zoom: 5
}, {
  searchControlProvider: 'yandex#map'
});
```

В чём может быть беда? И есть ли лёгкий способ ограничить выборку объектов по опрелелённому региону РФ?

Answer (score 0):

Вы указываете опции не в том поле, поэтому они не применяются к контролу поиска. Вот так будет работать:

```
        var searchControl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
        boundedBy:[[71.95152553383006,124.77785662500001],
                  [60.89422088315866,153.51809099999997]],
        noPlacemark: true,
        strictBounds: true
    }});
```